# Converting Text to mp3 or .wav to mp3 in C# (For Captcha Audio)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, text-to-speech

I am looking to take numbers generated from a captcha and have a control/link to allow the user to play it if they need to hear it. I currently have it using  System.Speech to generate this into a wav file. When attempting to find a method to allow the user to play this (was using a regular a href link) to open up a new page which ran the .aspx page and play the file, we ran into various issues across browsers.

IE(8 and 10) seemed to reset the session (which clears how I am getting the string from the captcha), Chrome worked fine, Firefox tried to infinitely load the page before timing out.

My boss wants to avoid using the google captcha, so my search continued.

We then came across the audio html tag. However, the drawback to this is for some reason IE won’t play .wav files in an audio tag.

So what I am seeking is a way to either:

1. Convert this .wav file into a MP3 which could be played on all browsers.
2. A way to force IE to play .wav files in the  tag.
3. Any suggestions as to make all the browsers treat my .wav file the same and play it after a trigger.

Thanks!

Here is my code to create the .wav file.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "audio/wav";
    string captchacode = Session["HologramID"].ToString();
    string[] num = captchacode.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
    captchacode = string.Join(" ", num);
    MemoryStream mstream = GetAudio(captchacode);
    mstream.Position = 0;
    mstream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
    Response.End(); 
}

public static MemoryStream GetAudio(string input)
{
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();

    var t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        synth.Rate = -5;
        synth.SetOutputToWaveStream(mem);
        synth.Speak(input);

    }));

    t.Start();
    t.Join();

    return mem;
}
```

Comment: Not a solution, but look into [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), it might give you an idea why rolling your own Captcha is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 audio player to play and httphandler (ashx) to stream mp3. However old browsers don't support html5 player. Instead you can use a flash player solution.

Craeta ashx handler that takes the captcha text and stream mp3 data.